# NVIDIA 384 doesn't start on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2

Tags: opensuse, nvidia

I followed a step-by-step [guide](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_the_hard_way) to download and install the NVIDIA driver on OpenSUSE Leap 42.2. The steps I followed are these.

```
$ su - root
# sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.90.run
# nvidia-xconfig
# echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf 
# mkinitrd 
# reboot
```

After rebooting, the system hangs right after starting the display manager and right before entering username/password. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I can start `tty1` and access the command line.

Did anybody run into this issue before?